# Using 'diff' with mismatched directories and filenames

Tags: shell, diff

I  have two separate folder directories, which mostly contain the same files, but the directory structure is completely different between the two folders. The filenames do not correspond either

So, for example:

```
FOLDER 1
--- Subfolder A
    -file1
    -file2
--- Subfolder B
    -file3
    -file4

FOLDER 2
--- Subfolder C
    -Subfolder C1
        -file5
        -file6
        -file7
    -Subfolder C2
        -file8
        -file9
```

Let's suppose that `file1=file5`, `file2=file6`, `file3=file7`, `file4=file8`
And `file9` is unmatched.

Is there some combination of options to the `diff` command that will identify the matches? Doing a recursive `diff` with `-r` doesn't seem to do the job.

Comment: Probably by calculating checksums you could find your `diff`. If filenames and directory structures do not match, this looks like the most painless option to me.

Comment: Thanks Kid Binary. That makes sense to me. I could code it up and do that, but it will take a bit of thought. Do you reckon there's no easy way to do this in terminal/command line?

Comment: Not aware of it... Answer by j.a. looks like a nice way to do it in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to get the **different** and/or **identical** files with [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs):

```
find FOLDER1 -type f -print0 |
xargs -0 -I % find FOLDER2 -type f -exec diff -qs --from-file="%" '{}' \+
```

Sample output:

> Files FOLDER1/SubfolderB/file3 and FOLDER2/SubfolderC/SubfolderC1/file5 differ
> Files FOLDER1/SubfolderB/file3 and FOLDER2/SubfolderC/SubfolderC1/file7 are identical

So, you can filter the ones you want with `grep` (see example).

*Notice this solution supports filenames with spaces and special characters (e.g.: newlines) embedded, so you don't have to worry about it*

#### Explanation

For every file in `FOLDER1` (`find FOLDER1 -type f -print0`), executes:

```
find FOLDER2 -type f -exec diff -qs --from-file="%" '{}' \+
```

That line calls `find` again to get all the files in `FOLDER2` and executes the following (processed):

```
diff -qs --from-file="<a file from FOLDER1>" <all the files from FOLDER2>
```

From [`man diff`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff):

> --from-file=FILE1
> Compare FILE1 to all operands. FILE1 can be a directory.

#### Example

This is the directory tree and the file content:

```
$ find FOLDER1 FOLDER2 -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "$0": &&  cat "$0"' '{}' \;
FOLDER1/SubfolderA/file1:
1=5
FOLDER1/SubfolderA/file2:
2=6
FOLDER1/SubfolderB/file3:
3=7
FOLDER1/SubfolderB/file4:
4=8
FOLDER2/SubfolderC/SubfolderC1/file5:
1=5
FOLDER2/SubfolderC/SubfolderC1/file6:
2=6
FOLDER2/SubfolderC/SubfolderC1/file7:
3=7
FOLDER2/SubfolderC/SubfolderC2/file8:
4=8
FOLDER2/SubfolderC/SubfolderC2/file9:
anything
```

And this is the command (pipeline) getting just the **identical** ones:

```
$ find FOLDER1 -type f -print0 |
> xargs -0 -I % find FOLDER2 -type f -exec diff -qs --from-file="%" '{}' \+ |
> grep "identical$"
Files FOLDER1/SubfolderA/file1 and FOLDER2/SubfolderC/SubfolderC1/file5 are identical
Files FOLDER1/SubfolderA/file2 and FOLDER2/SubfolderC/SubfolderC1/file6 are identical
Files FOLDER1/SubfolderB/file3 and FOLDER2/SubfolderC/SubfolderC1/file7 are identical
Files FOLDER1/SubfolderB/file4 and FOLDER2/SubfolderC/SubfolderC2/file8 are identical
```

---

#### Enhanced solution with `bash`'s [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) and [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays)

If you're using `bash`, you can first save all the `FOLDER2` filenames in an array to avoid calling `find` for each file in `FOLDER1`:

```
# first of all, we save all the FOLDER2 filenames (recursively) in an array
while read -d $'\0' file; do
    folder2_files=("${folder2_files[@]}" "$file")
done < <(find FOLDER2 -type f -print0)
# now we compare each file in FOLDER1 with the files in the array
find FOLDER1 -type f -exec diff -qs --from-file='{}' "${folder2_files[@]}" \; |
grep "identical$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary Git repository.  Add the first directory tree to it, and commit.

Remove all the files and add the second directory tree to it. Do the second commit.

The git diff between those two commits will turn on rename detection and you will probably see something more englightening.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Git, but would be happy to try this if it will do the job.  However, in my particular case the directories are very large (~50GB). Will that still be a suitable solution?